# How to color background of MDLabel properly in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, background-color, kivymd

Trying to color background of MDLabel (Label) in kivy app. But can not adjust width of the Label to be exactly the size of the text (content).

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        padding: dp(7)
        # pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        background_color: (1,1,0,1)
        height: self.minimum_height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            # pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            height: self.minimum_height
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Some text'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: self.texture_size
            MDLabel:
                id: trying_to_color_background
                text: 'Width'
                halign: 'right'
                size_hint_x: None
                size: self.texture_size
```

getting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9WCr.png)

if i try to remove last row of the code "size: self.texture_size". it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNoRu.png)

but i want the background to be the size of the text content (size of red border in the image below). if there will be more letters in the text, i want the background to be wider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHoMs.png)

Comment: There're two labels. Which label are you referring to and how ?

Comment: 2nd id is trying_to_color_background if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Set it as,

```py
            ...
            MDLabel:
                id: trying_to_color_background
                text: 'Width'
                halign: 'right'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                text_size: None, None
```

Comment: Thanks, will try tommorow

Comment: Works as I wanted.thank you very mush @ApuCoder

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
lbl_state = MDLabel(text="state", md_bg_color = [.119, .136, .153, 1])
```

2. 

```
lbl_state = MDLabel(text="state", theme_text_color = "Custom", md_bg_color = [.119, .136, .153, 1])
```

3. 

```
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

lbl_state = MDLabel(text="state", theme_text_color = "Custom", md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#7dcbb1"))
```

4. 

```
MDLabel:
   id: trying_to_color_background
   theme_text_color: "Custom"
   md_bg_color = .119, .136, .153, 1
```

Example for different colors:

```
0, 0, 0, 1 - dark
1, 1, 1, 1 - white
.7, .7, .7, 1 - gray
1, 0, 0, 1 - red
0, 1, 0, 1 - green
0, 0, 1, 1 - blue
```